# Multithreading with sockets JAVA

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

I have a problem with multithreading. I don't know why, but threads run in sequence.
There is a client-server application. I need to run several parallel threads for message exchange. The whole classes are too big, so I will show main parts.

Code of Client(This code runs every time when I push the button):

```
  public ArrayList<Action> call() {
        Thread myThready = new Thread(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                BufferedReader in;
                PrintWriter out;
                try{
                    Socket fromserver = new Socket(ip, PortID);
                    in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fromserver.getInputStream()));
                    out = new PrintWriter(fromserver.getOutputStream(),true);

                    writeLog(query, ID, 0);
                    out.println(query+"ID"+ID);
                    String fserver = in.readLine();
                    writeLog(fserver, ID, 1);
                    out.println("exit");
                    out.close();
                    in.close();
                    fromserver.close();
                }
                catch (IOException io){
                    return;
                }
            }
        });
        myThready.start();
}
```

Code of Server:

```
public void run(){
    flag=true;
    System.out.println("Welcome to Server side!");

    createLog();
    ExecutorService service = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
    ServerSocket servers = null;
    int n=4600;
    try{
    servers = new ServerSocket(n);
    } catch( Exception e){

    }
    Socket fromclient = null;

    while(true){
        try {
            System.out.print("Waiting for a client...");
            fromclient = servers.accept();
            System.out.println("Client connected.");
            Callable<ArrayList<Action>> callable = new HandleThread(fromclient);
            Future<ArrayList<Action>> future = service.submit(callable);

            list.addAll(future.get());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Can't accept.");
            System.exit(-1);
        }
    }
}
```

This code does "accept()" and then creates new thread for some calculations.

Code of HandleThread:

```
public ArrayList<Action> call() {
    BufferedReader in = null;
    PrintWriter out= null;
    try {
        in  = new BufferedReader(new
                InputStreamReader(fromclient.getInputStream()));
        out = new PrintWriter(fromclient.getOutputStream(),true);
        String         input,output;

        System.out.println("Wait for messages.");

        while ((input = in.readLine()) != null) {
            //close filewriter thread if input==exit
            if(input.equalsIgnoreCase("exit")){
                break;
            }
            System.out.println(input);
            String[] arr = input.split("ID");
            System.out.println("+"+arr[0]);
            ID = Integer.parseInt(arr[1]);
            writeLog(arr[0], ID, 0);
            process(arr[0], ID);
            out.println(arr[0]);
            writeLog(arr[0], ID, 1);
        }
        out.close();
        in.close();
        fromclient.close();

    } catch(IOException e){
        return null;
    }
    return list;
}
```

I don't know why this doesn't work. I have logs and I see that one thread runs only after another one. Not at the same time!
Please, help me!

Comment: This has nothing to do with the bug you're asking about but you might want to read up on proper resource cleanup, because your `HandleThread.call` could potentially leak both `in` and `out`, pre-java 7.  In 7, your `close()` calls are redundant.

Comment: What do you mean by these `in` and `out`?

Comment: Your `BuffreredReader in` and `PrintWriter out`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Future#get()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#get--) is a blocking call.

```
list.addAll(future.get());
```

The calling thread will wait until the task is done. As such, your server thread which calls `accept()` waits for each task to finish before it gets to the next one.

Comment: Okay, thanks. And how could I get the data without blocking other threads?

Comment: @user You can't get the data if the data is not ready. Why does your server thread need to have that information?

Comment: Well, I don't really need to get these data immediately. How should I do it correctly?

Comment: @user Correctly depends on what you want to do. If you don't need them now, store the futures and get their result later.

Comment: @user3051029 Well, a thread knows when _it_ finishes, so make it notify something or add its result somewhere.

Comment: `Executors.newCachedThreadPool()` can reuse threads, so it is easy to lose the result, if I will try to get it later.

Comment: @user3051029 This has nothing to do with `newCachedThreadPool`. Keep a reference to the `Future` instances somewhere. Call `get()` on them when you are ready to retrieve the results.